# Какой выбрать настольный компьютер для разработки десктопных программ под Windows (на C#)?

Tags: c#, windows, железо

***Photoshop'ом не пользуюсь, AutoCAD, Blender, Premier и ему подобные - тоже. Вместо Chrome - Edge. Бюджет - не важен (можно и в кредит), но важен самый оптимальный и бюджетный вариант. Виртуалки - не планируется (так как я буду разрабатывать исключительно под Windows). GNU/Linux - тоже. Я ещё новичок.***

Comment: Очевидно, с ОС Windows :)

Comment: Любой уважающий себя производитель программного обеспечения предоставляет минимальные требования к железу для работы.иВам нужно определиться с выбором софта и посмотреть рекомендации по железу

Comment: Возьмите что-нибудь на Ryzen 5, на что бюджета хватит. Памяти - тоже на сколько бюджета хватит, но хорошо бы, чтобы можно было докупить и поставить. Под систему и средства разработки хорошо бы SSD на сколько денег хватит опять же.

Comment: Берите хороший процессор (хотя бы i5),  памяти минимум 8гб, ssd тоже не помешает. Еще важно взять хорошую материнку. Но вообще, в общем случае, программировать можно и на старом пк, если вы только учитесь. Только на старом пк вы будете ждать дольше, когда у вас код будет собираться или запускаться.

Comment: Intel Core i5, 8GB RAM, SSD ~500GB, Windows 10, Visual Studio 2019 Community - и можно считать, что уже программист.

Comment: Добавил бы, что i5 лучше последнего поколения или присмотреться к i7.

Comment: @xxramm я отталкивался от минималок, ниже которых уже творить свой софт не собо комфортно.